# My var/log folder is taking too much space

Tags: 16.04, logs

My log folder details are as follows:
[image: Log folder files sizes]

Which files can i delete to free up my space??

Comment: In the future, please copy paste command output as text instead of an image.

Comment: The 21 **gigabyte** `kern.log` and 59 **gigabyte** `syslog` are where I'd start.

Comment: However, rather than just deleting the files, look them over to see what error and/or warnings are filling up the log and correct the error. Your system is screaming for your help!!! `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i error` Please don't post the entire thing here as it's far too loonnnngggggggg!

Comment: @chili555 My system crashed after doing that command and when i tried to restart, it stucks at a screen.

Comment: I can access the pc but it stucks at a screen.

Comment: Then try reading just a few lines at a time: `cat/var/log/syslog | grep -i error | less` Get out of 'less' with q. I suspect that it's getting stuck because of the underlying error.

Comment: Its stuck even after restart. I cant access anything.

Comment: @chili555 I can login with the screen stuck and access the terminal. I typed spd-say hello to check whether my terminal works. Any solution for fixing the screen stucked?

Comment: If you get to a black screen with a blinking prompt, that merely means that the graphics system is not working. I'm sure the error is in the log. I am not at all experienced with graphics. You need to see the error in the log somehow and fix it.

Comment: @chili555 Yeah i get lot of errors when the pc starts and is turned off. I'll try to fix them.

Comment: The syslog is spammed with error :
 sahil-HP-Pavilion-Notebook kernel: [    9.023521] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00000000
Dec 24 18:37:40 sahil-HP-Pavilion-Notebook kernel: [    9.023523] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Dec 24 18:37:40 sahil-HP-Pavilion-Notebook kernel: [    9.023917] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
Dec 24 18:37:40 sahil-HP-Pavilion-Notebook kernel: [    9.023924] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)

Comment: I suggest that you Google this: *pcieport  PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)* or ask a question here about it. I am inexperienced in such matters. I do know, however, that the answer is to fix the error, not just delete the file and ignore the error.